# Ethernet card on Windows 10 and ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, ethernet, windows-10

There're two systems on my computer, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.

They both work fine besides one thing:

Once I entered Ubuntu, the ethernet card will no longer usable for Windows. To be precise, the card can be detected by Windows, but the DHCP always return the address 169.254.*.*, Google says it's a common address for DHCP failure. Actually I have found a solution already: go to BIOS and disable the card after exit from Ubuntu, and then enable it again(PS: Doing this on Windows is useless, you must disable it on BIOS).

But doing such thing again and again is very annoying. So I ask you to help.

(Maybe Ubuntu write something in ethernet card so that Windows can not use it as normal? It's just my guess.)